# Getting "telegram.error.InvalidToken: You must pass the token you received from https://t.me/Botfather!"

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm working on a Telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot library, and I'm encountering an error that says "telegram.error.InvalidToken: You must pass the token you received from [https://t.me/Botfather!"](https://t.me/Botfather!%22). I've double-checked my token from BotFather and it's correct, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
import os
import openai
from telegram import Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CallbackContext, MessageHandler, filters
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_TOKEN")
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
```

I've also ensured that the .env file contains the correct token. The error occurs when I try to create the Bot and Updater instances. I'm using the correct version of the library (latest version) and I'm following the official documentation.

Am I missing something? Could someone please help me identify the root cause of this issue and provide suggestions for resolving it? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Have you tried just pasting in the token?

Comment: I suspect you are using the incorrect key for token. Triple-check your `.env`.

Answer (score 0):

My .env file was called token.env, my problem was gone just calling the file just .env